# How to completley disable all keyborad keys in CSS

Tags: css

Is there any style or property in CSS that can stop taking any input from keyboard until the property is there on the tag.

```
Dummycode
```

Comment: No, there is no such thing in CSS.

Comment: I know it can be done in JS but some how i was looking if it can be done in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable keyboard events with CSS.